# MS Access tables that need to be in the listbox

Tags: vb.net

OK, I have the worst VB class in the world. The friggin textbook has you do programming projects but the stupid book doesn't even explain everything required for the project.  Oh yeah, the professor for the class doesn't help worth a crap (online schooling).

So needless to say, I have been struggling with the class for a very VERY LONG TIME...

Well, here's my request:

[Here is visual representation of what is required](http://www.flickr.com/photos/83812754@N07/7708566510/in/photostream)

Now, I have been fighting this thing for MANY MANY hours and would like some tips and advice on how to get this stupid thing done.  I usually get more specific when it comes to posting in this website except this time, it seems like I have a problem with EVERYTHING!!!

Here is the instructions:
"The database Microland.accdb is maintained by the Microland Computer Warehouse, a mail-order computer-supply company. The tables below show data in the three tables in the database. The table Customers identifies each customer by an ID number and gives, in addition to the name and address, the total amount of purchases during the current year prior to today. The table Inventory identifies each product in stock by an ID number and gives, in addition to its description and price (per unit), the quantity in stock at the beginning of the day. The table Orders gives the orders received today. Assume that it is now the end of the day. Write a Visual Basic program that uses the three tables to do the following two tasks:

1. Display in a listbox the items that are out of stock and those that must be reordered to satisfy today’s orders.
2. Display in a listbox bills for all customers who ordered during the day. Each bill should show the customer’s name, address, items ordered (with costs), and total cost of the order.

So, if any of you VB geniuses would like to tell me how to do some of this stuff, that would be absolutely awesome.  Any kind of help will definitely make a difference for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming it's VB.NET) Here's some pointers on the bigger picture, you'll need Google to fill-in the details:

1) Establish a connection to your Access database using ADO.NET. Maybe do this in code or use the data tools in Visual Studio?

2) Write a query (in Access or plain SQL) to find the count of the distinct stock items that   have been purchased today and subtract that from the count of the items in stock at the beginning of the day. Select the items where the count is zero or less.
You can use the visual builder in Access and save the query object, referring to this query object in code. Or you can copy the SQL generated by Access and use this with ADO.NET command objects.

3) Show the results of this query in a listbox. Either step through the DataReader adding items to listbox in code, or investigate databinding to your datasource.

4) Write another query that shows the data requested in step 2 in your question and then list those results in another listbox.

Try to get a little further with it and then respond with progress and further issues.

Comment: Ok this is what I have (I kind of have to stick with the textbook):

Comment: Private Sub btnOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOut.Click
        Dim query1 = From Out In MICROLANDDataSet.Inventory
                     Where Out.quantity <= 10
                     Select Out.itemID, Out.quantity, Out.description

        lstOutput.Items.Clear()
        lstOutput.DataSource = query1.ToList
        lstOutput.SelectedItem = Nothing
    End Sub

Comment: Now the problem is that I am not getting anything to display in the listbox and I am getting this error :     "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." and it points to the "lstOutput.Items.Clear()".  I have no friggin idea what's going on...

Comment: Try removing the .Clear call, I don't think it's necessary. Also, I don't think the .SelectedItem = Nothing is required. Also, try only returning one field from the query at first, just to get the binding working. You can add additional fields later. Keep it as simple as possible to get it working and then layer on complexity as you go.